# prevent re-render child component react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have a 2 file react js,

1. AcademyRevision (Parent Page)
2. AcademyForm (Child Page)

the parent page is top of page and include child page inside, the child page is form page for view or edit data and child page have a props.

the problem is the child page always re-render when i type/change input value.

my parent component (AcademyRevision) :

```
import AcademyForm from "./components/academyForm";

export default function AcademyRevision(){
   ............
    return(
        <div className='page_wrap' style={{marginTop:60}}>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='fixed-top page_wrap shadow-md' style={{backgroundColor: '#FFF', height:100}}>
                    <div className='pt-5'>
                        <PageHeader title='Academy Data' style={{fontSize : '1.25rem', fontWeight : '600'}} is_back_btn={true} customBack={true} backToPage={() => backToParent()}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-12 mb-5">
                    <AcademyForm
                        title='Academy 1'
                        disabled={disableButton}
                        ipt_academy={ipt_academy1}
                        handleAcademy={handleAcademy1}
                        masterAcademyLevel={masterAcademyLevel}
                        ipt_school={ipt_school1}
                        set_ipt_school={(event, value) => set_ipt_school1(value)}
                        ipt_major={ipt_major1}
                        handleMajor={handleMajor1}
                        masterMajor={masterMajor}
                        ipt_start={ipt_start1}
                        set_ipt_start={(newValue) => set_ipt_start1(newValue)}
                        ipt_finish={ipt_finish1}
                        set_ipt_finish={(newValue) => set_ipt_finish1(newValue)}
                        ipt_description={ipt_description1}
                        set_ipt_description={(e) => set_ipt_description1(e.target.value)}
                        ipt_score={ipt_score1}
                        set_ipt_score={(e) => set_ipt_score1(e.target.value)}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

my child component (AcademyForm):

```
function AcademyForm({
    title,
    disabled,
    ///////////
    ipt_academy,
    handleAcademy,
    masterAcademyLevel,
    ipt_school,
    set_ipt_school,
    ipt_major,
    handleMajor,
    masterMajor,
    ipt_start,
    set_ipt_start,
    ipt_finish,
    set_ipt_finish,
    ipt_description,
    set_ipt_description,
    ipt_score,
    set_ipt_score
}){
    return(
        <div className={'custom-tabs-bg-solusiqu p-3 mb-3'}>
        {console.log('AcademyForm '+title)}
            <h5>{title}</h5>
            <div className="form-group row">
                <div className="col row">
                    <label className='custom-input-solusiqu col-6 col-form-label'>Academy</label>
                </div>
                <div className="col-12">
                    <FormControl 
                        required
                        disabled={disabled}
                        sx={{ width:'100%',
                            "& .MuiInputBase-input": {
                                fontSize: '0.9rem',
                            }
                        }}
                    >
                        <Select
                            size='small'
                            value={ipt_academy}
                            onChange={handleAcademy}
                        >
                            {
                            masterAcademyLevel?.map((data,index)=>(
                                <MenuItem key={index} value={data.CIDEDUCATION}>{data.CEDUCATION}</MenuItem>
                            ))
                            }
                        </Select>
                    </FormControl>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className='form-group row'>
                <div className="col row">
                    <label className='custom-input-solusiqu col-6 col-form-label'>School/Campus</label>
                </div>
                <div className="col-12">
                    <Autocomplete
                        onChange={set_ipt_school}
                        value={ipt_school}          
                        disabled={disabled}                 
                        options={masterSchool}
                        size='small'
                        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.CSCHOOL ? option.CSCHOOL: ""}
                        isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.CIDSCHOOL===value.CIDSCHOOL||value===''}
                        renderOption={(props, option) => {
                            return (
                              <li {...props} key={option.CIDSCHOOL}>
                                {option.CSCHOOL}
                              </li>
                            );
                        }}
                        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
                        sx={{ width:'100%',
                            "& .MuiInputBase-input": {
                                fontSize: '0.9rem',
                                textTransform:'uppercase',
                            }
                        }}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group row">
                <div className="col row">
                    <label className='custom-input-solusiqu col-6 col-form-label'>Major</label>
                </div>
                <div className="col-12">
                    <FormControl 
                        required
                        disabled={disabled}
                        sx={{ width:'100%',
                            "& .MuiInputBase-input": {
                                fontSize: '0.9rem'
                            }
                        }}
                    >
                        <Select
                            size='small'
                            value={ipt_major}
                            onChange={handleMajor}
                        >
                            {
                            masterMajor?.map((data,index)=>(
                                <MenuItem key={index} value={data.CIDMAJOR}>{data.CMAJOR}</MenuItem>
                            ))
                            }
                        </Select>
                    </FormControl>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group row pt-4">
                <div className="col-6">
                    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
                        <MobileDatePicker
                            value={ipt_start}
                            disabled={disabled}
                            label='Start'
                            size='small'
                            views={['year', 'month', 'day']}
                            onChange={set_ipt_start}
                            sx={{width: '100%',
                                "& .MuiInputBase-input": {
                                    height: '0.35em',
                                    fontSize: '0.9rem'
                                }
                            }}
                        />
                    </LocalizationProvider>
                </div>
                <div className="col-6">
                    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
                        <MobileDatePicker
                            value={ipt_finish}
                            disabled={disabled}
                            label='Finish'
                            size='small'
                            views={['year', 'month', 'day']}
                            onChange={set_ipt_finish}
                            sx={{width: '100%',
                                "& .MuiInputBase-input": {
                                    height: '0.35em',
                                    fontSize: '0.9rem'
                                }
                            }}
                        />
                    </LocalizationProvider>
                </div>
            </div>
            <ViewField
                data={ipt_description}
                disabled={disabled}
                inputClass='text-uppercase'
                type='text'
                useLabel={1}
                label='Description'
                onChange={set_ipt_description}
                style={{fontSize:'0.9rem'}}
            />
            <ViewField
                data={ipt_score}
                disabled={disabled}
                type='number'
                useLabel={1}
                label='Score'
                onChange={set_ipt_score}
                style={{fontSize:'0.9rem'}}
            />
        </div>
    )
}

export default memo(AcademyForm)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using **useRef** hook to get input box values , it will not  re-render the child component, read the docs first.

Comment: if using useReff hook, my input form will change to uncontrolled component where cannot put data to input default value

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: hey, sorry for my late response
for now i user useReff hook and it work, thank you..